# Cosmos db sql query with non alphanumeric collection name

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have collection with name "Branch_0c478bf0-8180-4353-9f7d-8cef940ee8b8_Collection" with special character "-". So, when I try perform sql query in azure portal(or from code) I have problem with collection name. 
What notation should I use with such collection name?

Example

```
select value count(1) 
from Branch_0c478bf0-8180-4353-9f7d-8cef940ee8b8_Collection as p 
where p.CustomerId = '0160c82e-86b4-4859-9b12-0f998205ddcb'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection name, in your query, is merely a placeholder. You actually apply the query to a collection object, and the name you use is just an alias.

You could have re-written the above as:

```
select value count(1) 
from p
where p.CustomerId = '0160c82e-86b4-4859-9b12-0f998205ddcb'
```

You can try this in the portal and see that it indeed works (assuming your original query works as designed, of course...).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really work and so simple. I must read documentation more attentively.